# Factory method pattern & data abstraction in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I try to implement the [Factory Method Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method/cpp/1) in C++ while keeping a good level of abstraction. In the sample provided in the link, all derived classes are in the same file, but this is usually not the case.

1. **Without header files for derived classes:**
   To keep implementation details, I didn't provide a header file for the derived class (declaration & definition in the source file), then I don't see how to implement the factory method because the derived classes are not visible and forward declaration is not possible.
2. **With header files for derived classes:**
   I can implement the factory method, but the implementation details of derived classes leak because the private members and methods have to be declared in the header.

Maybe using the [PImpl idom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) can help to solve the problem in case 2) but I wonder if this is correct/reasonable approach. What is the usual/best way to implement this pattern in C++ ?

Here is my code:

```
//graphic-api.hpp

class GraphicApi {
public:

    enum class Type {
        //OPENGL,
        //DIRECTX,
        VULKAN
    };

    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual ~GraphicApi() {};

    static std::unique_ptr<GraphicApi> make(const Window& window, Type type);

};

//graphic-api.cpp 

//need to include headers for derived classes
std::unique_ptr<GraphicApi> GraphicApi::make(const Window& window, GraphicApi::Type type) {
    switch (type) {
    case GraphicApi::Type::VULKAN:
        return std::make_unique<VulkanApi>(window);
    default:
        assert(0 && "Unsupported Graphic API");
    }
    return nullptr;
}

//vulkan-api.hpp
class VulkanApi : public GraphicApi {
public:
    VulkanApi(const Window& window);
    virtual void render() {};

private:

    // lot of private members & methods related to Vulkan API (not nice to see here)     
    vk::UniqueInstance instance;
    ...
};
```

Comment: The pattern is logically correct, nothing to add here. But I see a problem as a library. Looks like your library must be linked statically or dynamically with three different libraries, OpenGL, Vulcan and DirectX. You bring all the libraries, but will be used only one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I will use only one at a time, I may have a try and fail initialization (like try vulkan if not supported use OpenGL). I am not so familar with C++ not sure if this is possible actually. About Vulkan, I am using vk::DynamicLoader (as a member of my class), this class is loading the DLL, I suppose the DLL is loaded only if the class is created ?

Comment: I don't know Vulkan, that is details that you should be aware of in order to not tie your code binary to big sledgehammers that you always should bring with you. The fact that your binary should be aware of `vk::DynamicLoader` is already a problem. It is ok if the program uses all of them. Maybe `vk::DynamicLoader` itself is not that a big sledgehammer, so maybe is not a big problem. That's your part of problem to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will take this in consideration. Indeed, this is not so useful to include all libraries if I know the target plateform of my build.